# Button on click event

Tags: jquery

I have a button on the left side of my home page and when I click that button I want to show a form on the right side of the page without changing the content of the home page
How ?

Comment: Could you Please Share Some Code?

Answer (score 1):

Initially hide the form using css `display:none;`. Then on button click write the code to display the form

```
$('.button').click(function(){
  $('#form_id').show(); // Selector of form
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Initially hide the form and then on button click show the form.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(#formId).hide();
    $(".button-class").click(function() {
        $(#formId).show();
    });
});
```

Comment: Why to use jquery to hide the form if it can be done via css ?

Comment: The form is still there it’s not hidden

Comment: Can we do this like , when button is clicked I need to run a function and inside that function we use . Html and include the form inside

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div class="containerDiv">
<div id="leftdiv" class="leftdivclass">hello123
<button onclick="showForm()">
show form
</button>
</div>
<div id="rightdiv" class="rightdivclass">hello321
<form id="myForm" class="formClass">
<button>
testvbutton
</button>
<input value="test"/>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function showForm() {
    $("#myForm").show();
}
```

CSS:

```
.containerDiv {
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:space-between;
}
.rightdivclass {
  display: inline-block;
}
.leftdivclass {
  display: inline-block;
}
.formClass {
  display:none;
}
```

Comment: Now the form is hided

Comment: Now the form is hided but when I click the button it’s not showing?

Comment: Check this [form code link](https://jsfiddle.net/4djtp2eh/23/)